# Objective-C completion block in Swift errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsdictionary, nsobject

I'm trying to run a method from an Objective-C class with a completion block in a Swift class but I'm having some troubles.

Obj-C code:

```
typedef void(^completionBlock)(NSDictionary *);

+ (void)getVersionsFromAPI:(completionBlock)sendData
{
  NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
  // Do stuff
  sendData(dict);
}
```

Swift code:

```
API.getVersionsFromAPI { (ver : NSDictionary) -> Void in
    self.version = ver.mutableCopy() as NSMutableDictionary;
}
```

I'm getting an error that says `'[NSObject : AnyObject]!' is not a subtype of 'NSDictionary'` on the first line.

Comment: Have you tried using `ver : NSDictionary!` or `ver : NSDictionary?`?

Comment: Yep, that then says `'[NSObject : AnyObject]!' is not identical to 'NSDictionary'` when using `!` or the first error with `?`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume that the `version` property is an optional `NSMutableDictionary`:

```
var version: NSMutableDictionary?
```

If that's correct, than you should fix your code as follows:

```
API.getVersionsFromAPI { (ver: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) in
    if let ver = ver {
        self.version = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: ver)
    }
}
```

I've successfully compiled this code in Xcode 6.1.1